# Unhandled Exception: type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'PickedFile' in type cast

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I'm trying to make it where the user is able to change their profile pic inside the app.
I'm able to pull the camera and take a picture in flutter. However, the image is not being saved, and inside visual studio code I
get the following error: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'PickedFile' in type cast

Here are the variables I'm using:

```
PickedFile? _imageFile;
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
```

Here is the function where they're being used:

```
void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: source);
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile as PickedFile;
    });
  }
```

Also, I'm using the latest version of image picker, which is image_picker: ^0.8.4+4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<File?> takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: source);                  
    
    final File? file = File(image!.path);
    return file;
  }
```

The issue is with using declaring it as a PickedFile initially.

Answer (score 1):

you can try change `PickedFile` -> `XFile`  ? because you are using new version. And now they use `XFile` instead of `PickedFile`.
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/55e246bfa0fd43ff16dc0041084449e606d0fb3c/packages/image_picker/image_picker/lib/image_picker.dart#L203

If you want continue use `PickedFile` let change to `getImage`

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your declaration to:

```
XFile _imageFile;
```

Instead of pickedfile. And remove the case in `as PickedFile`